# Process parameters of a POST HTTP request in a REST web service (JERSEY)

Tags: http, google-app-engine, jersey, httprequest

I'm developing a rest web service on GAE. I'm using Jersey framework to implement the services. It is a POST service where I have to pass also parameters. I tried to use 2 types of annotation but I can't get the parameters:

@Context

```
@POST
@Path("add")
@Produces( { MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public Notification addUser(@Context UriInfo uriInfo){
    MultivaluedMap<String, String> queryParams = uriInfo.getQueryParameters();
    String nickname = queryParams.getFirst("nickname");
    String name = queryParams.getFirst("name");
    String surname = queryParams.getFirst("surname");
    String telephone = queryParams.getFirst("telephone");
    String email = queryParams.getFirst("email");
    User =createUser(nickname, name, surname, telephone, email);

    .......
}
```

@QueryParam

```
@POST
@Path("add")
@Produces( { MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public Notification addUser(@QueryParam("nickname") String nickname, @QueryParam("name") String name, @QueryParam("surname") String surname, @QueryParam("telephone") String telephone, @QueryParam("email") String email) {
    User =createUser(nickname, name, surname, telephone, email);
    ......
}
```

But in both cases I can not get the parameters all of them are null values.

this is an example of my http request:

```
Request URL: http://windyser.appspot.com/rest/users/add
Request Method: POST
Params: {"nickname":"prova","name":"danilo","surname":"delizia","email":"prova@yahoo.it","telephone":"123"}
Sent Headers
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Accept-Language: en
```

Anybody know if I'm missing something?

Thanks in advance for your help

Danilo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jetty 8.x supports Java EE 6 and Jetty 7.x supports only Java EE 5.
I see from your first code snippet that you use "@Produces" annotation from Java EE 6. It must be the problem.

To fix:

1. Make sure you are using GAE SDK bundled with Jetty 8.x to support the annotation -or-
2. Use Java EE 5 facilities only.

---

[EDIT]

Let the service know that you need to consume String parameters. Try to use @Consumes runtime annotation:

```
@POST
@Path("/add")
@Produces( { MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
@Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded") // to consume String parameters
public Notification addUser(@FormParam("nickname") String nickname) {        
    ......
}
```

next if you need to access the service:

```
URL url = new URL("http://[HOST]:[PORT]/[CONTEXT]/?nickname=prova"); // Your parameter
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.connect();            

// Get the response
BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
String line;
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line); // Your service's response
}
rd.close();
conn.disconnect()
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Surlac, I tried as u said with the @Consumes("text/plain") and @Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded") annotations, but it still does not work. In the first case I get an "Unsupported Media Type" from GAE. And the second case i get null parameters. Any clue on how I can do it???

Comment: Try to use @FormParam in your POST-method signature as I described in the answer.